# Regular expression in PHP to return array with all images from html, eg: all src="images/header.jpg" instances

Tags: php, html, regex

I'd like to be able to return an array with a list of all images (src="" values) from html

> [0] = "images/header.jpg" 
>   [1] = "images/person.jpg"

is there a regular expression that can do this?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/src="([^"]+)"/`

The image will be in group 1.

Example:

```
preg_match_all('/src="([^"]+)"/', '<img src="lol"><img src="wat">', $arr, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

Returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => src="lol"
            [1] => src="wat"
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => lol
            [1] => wat
        )

)
```

Comment: `<script src="foo.js"></script>` — Regular expressions do not play well with HTML, overly simplistic regular expressions less so.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the world of the millionth "how to exactract these values using regex" question ;-) I suggest to use the search tool before seeking an answer -- here is just a handful of topics that provide code to do exactly what you need;

- [replacing all image src tags in HTML text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363065/replacing-all-image-src-tags-in-html-text)
- [getting image src in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085016/getting-image-src-in-php)
- [How to extract img src, title and alt from html using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138313/how-to-extract-img-src-title-and-alt-from-html-using-php)
- [Matching SRC attribute of IMG tag using preg_match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180255/matching-src-attribute-of-img-tag-using-preg-match)
- [php regex : get src value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695989/php-regex-get-src-value)
- [Dynamically replace the “src” attributes of all <img> tags (redux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808746/dynamically-replace-the-src-attributes-of-all-img-tags-redux)
- [preg_match_all , get all img tag that include a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528541/preg-match-all-get-all-img-tag-that-include-a-string)

Comment: And _regular expressions are not a solution for this_.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more polished version of the regular expression provided by [Håvard](/users/320616/h%c3%a5vard):

```
/(?<=src=")[^"]+(?=")/
```

This expression uses Lookahead & Lookbehind Assertions to get only what you want.

```
$str = '<img src="/img/001.jpg"><img src="/img/002.jpg">';

preg_match_all('/(?<=src=")[^"]+(?=")/', $str, $srcs, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

print_r($srcs);
```

The output will look like the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => /img/001.jpg
            [1] => /img/002.jpg
        )

)
```

Comment: using src regex get js also in my case ( for example : [28] => /modules/jcarousel/assets/carousel_start.js )

Answer (score 1):

I see that many peoples struggle with [Håvard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/320616/h%C3%A5vard)'s post and `<script>` issue. Here is same solution on more strict way:

`<img.*?src="([^"]+)".*?>`

Example:

```
preg_match_all('/<img.*?src="([^"]+)".*?>/', '<img src="lol"><img src="wat">', $arr, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

Returns:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => "lol"
            [1] => "wat"
        )

)
```

This will avoid other tags to be matched. [HERE is example](https://regex101.com/r/eEyf5S/2).