# How to extract image names with PHP or regex?

Tags: php, regex

I have the following data in MySQL.

```
<p><img src="../../../../assets/images/frontpage/image1.png" 
alt="" width="790" height="356" /></p>
```

Now I want to get image2.png with PHP or regex. The extension can be gif or jpg. And a length of image name can be any length.

Comment: Worth noting is whether you want to be able to match this on multiple img-tags or just one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650125/how-to-parse-html-with-php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression in PHP to return array with all images from html, eg: all src="images/header.jpg" instances](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721025/regular-expression-in-php-to-return-array-with-all-images-from-html-eg-all-src)

Comment: And, of course, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: "I want to get image2.png with PHP or regex" doesn't really tell us what you're trying to do. "Get" image2.png how? Your example has "image1.png".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would match a path in an img tag and capture the file in the first interior capturing group.

```
<?php
if (preg_match('%<img\s.*?src=".*?/?([^/]+?(\.gif|\.png|\.jpg))"%s', $subject, $regs)) {
    $image = $regs[1];
} else {
    $image = "";
}
?>
```

Comment: This outputs, ../../../assets/images/frontpage/image1.png

Comment: I needed to change a capture-all to a group.  I think it should work now.

Comment: I added the following to the above code and it works. $path = explode('/', $image);
$image_name = end($path);
return $image_name;

Answer (score 0):

This code should do what you need:

```
<?php
$regex = '@src[ ]*=[ ]*"[a-z/.]*/(.*?\.(?:png|gif|jpg))@i"';
$match = array();
if (preg_match($regex, $html, $match)) {
    $imglocation = $match[1];
} else {
    die('Failed to find image name.');
}
```

Comment: $html = '<p><img src="../../../../assets/images/frontpage/image1.png" 
alt="" width="790" height="356" /></p>';
$regex = 'src[ ]*=[ ]*"[a-zA-Z/.]*/(.*?\.(?:png|gif|jpg))"';
$match = array();
if (preg_match($regex, $html, $match)) {
    $imglocation = $match[1];
} else {
    die('Failed to find image name.');
}. This gives the following error. Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test1.php on line 19
Failed to find image name.

Comment: Whoops, I forgot to include a delimiter. Added now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$str = '<p><img src="../../../../assets/images/frontpage/image1.png" 
alt="" width="790" height="356" /></p>'; 
$imageType = end(explode("."));
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this expression: `var expr=/[a-z]+\.(gif|jpg)$/;`

Comment: this will return an array so you can get image1.jpg getting by 0th index of array :)

Comment: @Tomalak it looks like Javascript to me.